# List of News Articles In Sitecore (Best Approach?)

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I am creating a Sitecore MVC site for a client and I need to create page that will list news articles for the company.

So far, I have created items that use a shared data template called “Article,” and I also have a sublayout (a view rendering) called “Article” that will display these items.

For the list itself, my plan was to create another component (a sublayout) call “News_List”, and to put a placeholder in it called “List”.

My question is this: *can I allow the author to insert articles (e.g., N items of type “Article”) into this placeholder via the page editor?*

Will SC allow you to insert multiple instances of the same component into a placeholder?  Will this break anything?

I believe this is a pretty common question but I have not found a definitive answer.  Thanks in advance…!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert as many components (of the same type) in your placeholder as you want..  Just make sure to put the placeholder settings correctly and give it a decent name (not just "list" ;))

But are you sure you want to do this? Your editors will manually need to create a list of components for each article they want to add on the page. Doesn't sound to be very user (editor) friendly.. Maybe you should consider creating a list component that can get a list of articles as a datasource and show those. Or even select them automatically (but that might be not according to your business case)..

Comment: I would say that having 3 question marks in an answer is probably a good indicator that it's more appropriate as a comment

Comment: Well, I was just going to modify the placeholder settings for the "List" placeholder to allow the author to "Add to Here" items that are Articles. This should work, right?

Comment: It will work, but as I said your editors will have quite some work setting up this page and maintaining it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, authors can add multiple instances of the same component into a single placeholder.

Assuming that the code of the component doesn't do any stupid things it's absolutely ok to do this.